# ParseKeyValueStore in ParseSwift SDK, backingStore Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am struggling to understand what is the idea of `keyValueStore` in the ParseSwift initializer. These are my first steps with Parse and this SDK also as I decided to not use Firebase at the end.

Starting with simple init in AppDelegate:

```
ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: "...",
                              clientKey: "...",
                              serverURL: URL(string: "https://...")!)
```

For the learning purpose I created user struct:

```
struct ParseUsr: ParseUser {
    
    //: These are required for `ParseObject`.
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?

    //: These are required for `ParseUser`.
    var username: String?
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
    var authData: [String: [String: String]?]?
    
    
}
```

then when my app launch I am checking if current user is nil, for simplicity, just print it:

```
print(ParseUsr.current)
```

but upon retrieving there is a nil on line 46, ParseStorage.swift -> "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" for `backingStore`

later I tried also to add keyValueStore in the initialiser:

```
ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: "...",
                              clientKey: "...",
                              serverURL: URL(string: "https://...")!, keyValueStore: KeyChain())
```

class for KeyChain is empty implementation so far, but that should not cause the above nil exception on `backingStore`:

```
class KeyChain: ParseKeyValueStore {
    
    func delete(valueFor key: String) throws {
         
    }
    
    func deleteAll() throws {
         
    }
    
    func get<T>(valueFor key: String) throws -> T? where T : Decodable {
        return nil
    }
    
    func set<T>(_ object: T, for key: String) throws where T : Encodable {
         
    }
 }
```

Could you please give me a hint how to use the local persistence of current user?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was something that I believe is called "code race":

I did call the initialiser in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and as it does asynchronous init, another code in the first viewController's `viewDidLoad` was executing faster and therefore calling `print(user.current)` before the Parse was initialised.

I moved Parse init as first in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it is working fine now.